# How to connect Facebook page to Reddit page?

Tags: facebook, reddit

I have a Facebook page from where I wanted to share the new posts that I post on my Facebook page to Reddit page. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using their respective API's. Here a link to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) and here's one for [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/). This shouldn't be to hard to set up if you have some coding experience, in the relevant languages.